# Using ServiceSecurityContext.Current with WCF/Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I want to use the current Windows user for my Silverlight application. Using any other application I can just use `WindowsIdentity`, but it seems I need to use `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` with WCF. My problem is that the `.Current` comes out as `null`.

Apparently this is because of the transport mode I'm using. My problem is that Silverlight can't use `TransportWithMessageCredential` apparently without it wanting to use Https.

So I try using `TransportWithMessageCredential` and my service starts saying it's expecting Https, but is receiving Http.

I've looked around on the web and it seems I need to use wsHttpBinding (which isn't available with Silverlight) or some form of access policy to use Https with Http (which doesn't seem to work).

Surely there's an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing a few things:

1) `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in the web.config file

2) `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />` in the web.config file. `aspnetCompatibilityEnabled` is the important one here.

3) `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]` attribute on my WCF service class.

4) Use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity` to get the windows identity.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"